# None of the apps installed on my SD card work anymore

Tags: applications, sd-card

The apps worked this morning for a bit, then I plugged my phone in to charger and grabbed it right before I left for work.

When I was checking it on the way to work, most if not all of my apps, said 'Application is not installed on your phone'.

I've tried restarting many times and un-mounting and mounting the SD card again.

Can anyone help, please?!

Comment: Something does not sound right about this! Why did you unmount the SDCard? are the apps on SDCard? what device, what Android version, what exactly happened to get that message?

Comment: I unmounted the SD card because all of the applications that are not working say SD next to them on the application menu. On the home screen it just displays a little android guy in place of the app icon. I figured the card was not in properly or something so I unmounted & remounted it. I can't even access the Play store because that says it's not installed on phone as well. When i go to settings and applications it says there are a few installed on SD card but the ones installed are gray and have the SD next to them. I have the Samsung Galaxy SII and the Android version 4.0.4

Comment: Let me clarify, in the settings - applications in the 'Downloaded' section it shows the gray apps with SD next to them. In the 'On SD card' section it shows 4 apps that work. Very confusing!

Comment: I plugged it into my wall charger.

Comment: Not exactly sure now... the sdcard was probably unmounted and replaced the usual application icon with the android guy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to post a screenshot of my phone on here, I've tried several different HTML codes from the help section, but it doesn't show the image. Thought it might help understand a bit better? Sorry, not as familiar with the codes as I used to be. Thanks for your help though @t0mm13b